# How to translate "a detail-oriented person"?

Tags: translation

If you go to a job interview and say, "I am a detail-oriented person", it doesn't come off as a negative trait. But I feel when someone says `私は細かい事を気にする人です`, it has some negative connotation to it.  Is there a way to say "a detail-oriented person" in Japanese that doesn't come off as a negative trait?

Comment: I know nothing about interviews in Japanese, but I would be surprised if you'd say something like that at all.

Comment: yea generally you wouldn't say 細かい事を気にする人 about yourself i think

Comment: You do not use a first-person pronoun in a job interview.  Who else could you be talking about?

Comment: I think it s a difficult one to say in English (do you still give priority to what is important?) but a different tack such saying you are thorough (徹底的) might work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the "気にする人" part and say like this:

> 私は細かい事によく気がつく人だと思います。

Now this sounds positive and suitable for presenting yourself.

And you can use a more neutral word [几帳面【きちょうめん】](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/52781/m0u/) (na-adjective):

> 私は几帳面な性格なので、細かい書類の管理や事務作業は得意です。

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd say it like...

> 細部に注意を払います。

Though maybe it'd be a little more humble to say it like...

> 細部に注意を払うように努めています。

Comment: ah this is a good one. i completely forgot about 細部. thanks!

Comment: No problem. I'd accept naruto's answer since he's a native speaker and has undoubtedly suggested a more natural expression.

Answer (score 0):

I've found "attention to detail" as `細部への気配り`.  So perhaps you could say something like `細部への気配り者`.

Comment: 「気配り者」はちょっと変なので、「細部への気配りができる人」がいいと思います。